# Casino problem Similar to Roulette

Tags: probability

Consider a Setup similar to roulette , but here we have 1-36 numbers.
Where Number 12,24 and 36 gives 17 Times , but rest of the numbers gives 34 times amount that is bid on number.

While the **calculation of Casino house edge**, I am having doubt at my way of calculation

As the probability of getting a number is 1/36 in Idle setup.
Now if we bid on the number which is one of the 33 number(one that returns 34 times), the probability is (1/33)

house edge would be (1/33)*34-(32/33)

Now if we are bidding on one of the number that returns 17 times ie . 12 ,24 and 36

Then would the house edge be (1/3)* 17 -(2/3)

I am bit doubtfull of my calculation , can someone suggest or confirm about my steps of house edge calculation.

Comment: Why would anybody ever bet on $12$ or $24$ or $36$?

Comment: i do agree with you , but if it is there then can you tell me what i am doing is right in calculations.To make problem more biased to these three number , say if person gets 12 then he or she wins 34 times plus 17 time the bid.

Comment: Say person gets 12 or 24 or 36 , he or she wins 34 plus 17 times the bid

Comment: you'll never see such roulette in real casino